# vuejs 3.0: why is a component event handler getting called recursively one extra time?

Tags: dom-events, vuejs3

Before I get into the details, I'm working with a tree of components about 3 or 4 deep, and just added a new one between the parent component and one of the lower-level leaves. I have an `@input` handler but it's called twice for each change, the first time with the input event. I then call `this.$emit('parentEventName', event)` to pass the value to the parent, and after it's been processed, my lower-level handler is called again with event parameter set to the value rather than the event object.

Is this a rank programming error or is there some subtlety at work?  I added `event.stopProgation()` and `event.preventDefault()` calls but they have no effect. And, no, I can't do something like `<template-name @input.stop.prevent="handler"...` because the second time the handler is called the event object doesn't have those two methods the shortcut expands to.

Comment: I'm not sure anyone can help you without posting some code. Please read how to create [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Completely agree. The code's part of a bigger project and the owner was off yesterday. It's part of an electron app, not trivial to isolate, and was hoping someone would be familiar with the problem and have a fix.

Answer (score 0):

Here's why: the lower-level component is sending a non-event object as its second param (`this.$emit('eventName', 42)`). *Something* is fabricating a regular event object that wraps this value, and I'm not sure how it gets funneled into the outer-level event handler, but that's the best I can do at explaining it.

To make matters more interesting, the code is supposed to be used by both vue v2 and v3 apps. So I added a test - if we're running v3 code, send the event object and ignore the others, and v.v. for v2.